# Update random number in a SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I am currently working on survey to display a random questions, For that i need to update random numbers to a sobject. But System.NullPointerException: occurred in my code.

**Apex:**

```
public class update_random_question 
{
public   List<Question__c> scope{get;set;}
public update_random_question()
{
    for(Question__c a : scope)
    {
        a.orderby__c = randomizer.getRandomNumber(100);            
    }
update scope;
} }
```

**VF:**

```
<apex:page controller="update_random_question">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton Value="Begin" action="{!update_random_question}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Notes:**  [randomizer.getRandomNumber](http://www.codebycody.com/2012/02/sfdc-randomizer.html)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to write a batch?

Comment: Need to update a column `orderby` field with random number each time during a start of survey.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a test class covering the different scenarios you expect to see. It will help you understand how your code works and where it can break (design by test). You'll need one anyway in order to deploy it.

Comment: @crmprogdev Can you please modify the code accordingly, I am new to SF,  my table structure is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialized "scope", so it has a null value (it does not contain any value). Use a constructor to initialize your data:

```
public update_random_question() {
    scope = [SELECT Id FROM Question__c];
}
```

Change the query to meet whatever criteria you'd like.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot, your small contribution  helps me lot.